# Is it possible to port and use Nhibernate CriteriaAPI in Silverlight over WCF

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, nhibernate, data-access-layer

I was going to write and use some kind of criteria API in Silverlight project to pass complex dynamic requests to WCF service.

At first I thought about using QueryObject like:
UserQuery {int? AgeMin; int? AgeMax; string NameContains; string NameStartWith;} etc if some property is not null than we use some kind of filter on it, but what about logic operators? (And Or) I have no way to specify this logic using QueryObject.

So I was going to write some kind of criteria API with predicate builder which combines the AND, OR expressions, but I already using NHibernate criteria API on server side why just not to rip it out of Nhibernate in Silverlight class library? I found no evidence in Internet on using NHibernate criteria API in Silverlight, this is kinda strange, it's not possible to rip it out of Nhibernate or it makes no sense? Why is it not used? To me it's looks like a good solution, better than coding your own API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> building queries on the client is not a good idea

1. What about 3d party DataGrid controls (Telerik, DevExpress, Infragistics) that contain query builders and allow user to compose custom complex queries on client side?
2. What about RIA Services, that exposes database query interface.

This sounds like cliche. People just constantly repeat it because they read it somewhere, but they don't know why.

I disagree with this, I think the ability to compose custom complex queries on client side is a reasonable requirement for data oriented Line Of Business applications.

Answer (score 0):

to add to peer's answer- it's **never** a good idea to get queries which are constructed on client-side. on intranet or any other kind of application.
QueryObjects *are* the way to go.
you can create the expression on the client side (such as `(Name like '%blah' or LastName like 'something') and Id > 5`), and on the server side- use .net's [expression trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) (see also [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546158.aspx)), or implement your own engine ([general idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121812/building-expression-tree)).

Comment: Expressions trees is surely not a way to go, security risk is much larger, you can put any MethodCall expression in tree, so it's basycaly remote code executions.